# How to install libappindicator1 on Python of Docker image?

Tags: python, docker

I'd like to install goole chrome on  Python of  Docker image. So, I need install `libappindicator1`. However when I build this Dockerfile, I got error on `libappindicator1`

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

# Install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils fonts-takao-*

# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
```

#### Error message

```
E: Unable to locate package libappindicator1
```

How can I install libappindicator1 on Python of Docker image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this problem by modifying the python image tag.

`python: 3.8` ->  `python: 3.8-buster`

When I use `python: 3.8-bullseye` I got the same error. So this error seems to be related with Debian 10 (bullseye).

Note: buster is Debian 9

This is the reason, why Debian 10 (bullseye) can not install `libappindicator1`

[5.3.1. Noteworthy obsolete packages](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/armel/release-notes/ch-information.en.html)

> The deprecated libappindicator libraries are no longer provided. As a result, the related packages libappindicator1, libappindicator3-1 and libappindicator-dev are no longer available. This is expected to cause dependency errors for third-party software that still depends on libappindicator to provide system tray and indicator support.

Comment: I just want to thank you for making my misery end.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.